# adding Custom listview to fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-listfragment, custom-adapter

I have an activity containing a custom listview.

It has a custom array adapter (as another java file) and a setter and getter class (as another java file).
I want to put this custom listview into a fragment but I always get error.
This is my main activity code before:
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
private ListView listView;
private List<NameBean> items;
private NamesAdapter objAdapter = null;
private Button btnGetSelected;
public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
    "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
String CheckedItems;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
    btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

    items = new ArrayList<NameBean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NameBean nb = new NameBean();
        nb.setName(titles [i]);
        nb.setSpinnerAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        items.add(nb);
    }
    objAdapter = new NamesAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ...
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    ...
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this is how I want to use it inside Fragment:

public class Content extends Fragment{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

    return view;
}
public void setThings(ListAdapter adapter) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

}

I defined these parameters inside another Fragment (in the same Activity):

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private List<NameBean> items;
private NamesAdapter objAdapter = null;
public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
    "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
String CheckedItems;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items,
            container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

// May also be triggered from the Activity
public void updateDetail() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    items = new ArrayList<NameBean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NameBean nb = new NameBean();
        nb.setName(titles [i]);
        nb.setSpinnerAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        items.add(nb);
    }
    objAdapter = new NamesAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    Content fragment = (Content) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
        fragment.setThings (objAdapter);
    } 
}
```

}

I don't know what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: You're unlikely to get help if you don't even say what your error is. We don't know what the problem is, either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be enough, but:

1. Your `Content` class should extend ListFragment, not just Fragment. By default, `ListFragment` has a view hierarchy containing a `ListView` and nothing else; if you want to supply your own layout, that's fine, but your `ListView` within that layout must have the ID `@id/android:list`. See the [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) javadoc.
2. In your `setThings(ListAdapter)` method, you should pass the `ListAdapter` to the fragment's `setListAdapter()` method, not directly to the `ListView`, like this:

   ```
   public void setThings(ListAdapter adapter) {
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.